# Spring @Transactional concurrency solutions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

> The concurrency problem in Spring Boot is to use the @Transactional annotation. This annotation ensures that the data is accessed and modified in a transaction, which means that multiple threads cannot modify the same data at the same time. If two or more threads try to access the same data, one thread must wait for the transaction to complete before modifying the data.

Is this statement completely accurate for Spring Transactional annotation? I read conflicting things in a couple of articles, but based on my understanding, the Transactional annotation is per thread. So, in theory, another thread can access the same data that a thread is currently accessing at the same time.

Could someone please shed light on this?

Comment: As far as I know the quote you have provided is not part of spring documentation, that in turn means you are trying to discuss someone's opinion on that topic, that is much better to address your question to the initial author.

Comment: What's the source of your quote?